# How to modify a SharePoint 2013 Workflow Task Form?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, custom-form

I am trying to customize the workflow task form in my SharePoint 2013 Workflow created in SharePoint Designer. I am using SharePoint Online. What I've done currently is the following:

- Created a SP2013 Workflow in SharePoint Designer 2013. The workflow just has a single action **Assign a Task** which assigns a task to myself using the default options (Approve / Reject)
- Go to Workflow Tasks List in browser and click "Customize in InfoPath"
- In InfoPath, just Publish the default form.

My problem now is that when I click the **New Task** button on the Workflow Tasks List, I am redirected to the InfoPath form just fine. But if for example, the task is created via the workflow, the View / Edit Form just displays the default SharePoint form and not the InfoPath one.

How can I modify this so that tasks created by the workflow will also use the InfoPath Form?

EDIT:

I tried looking at the Forms section on the workflow in SharePoint Designer but can't find any option to create a new or edit any existing form. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to open the workflow itself in SharePoint Designer and you will find a `Forms` (A list of the forms used by this workflow) section. There you will find the Task form. Open that form in info-path and modify and save.

Comment: I can't see any form I can edit or even a button to create a new one. I've edited my question to include a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the Task List. In your Lists and Libraries it should be a couple of lists named "Tasks" and "Workflow Tasks" in the latter is where you will find the forms for your workflow

Answer (score 0):

Add an Initiation Form parameter at the top menu and save the workflow, the form should be automatically created then